# What are the steps this JavaScript program takes

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain the steps this program takes and the order in which they are taken in order to produce the result "false"

```
function negate(func) {
  return function(x) {
    return !func(x);
  };
}
var isNotNaN = negate(isNaN);
show(isNotNaN(NaN));
```

Comment: no, I`m actually an old guy trying to learn Javascript on my own...I wish it was homework because I`d then have a teacher!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  // 1. A function called "negate is declared
function negate(func) {  // 3. The "isNaN" function is received by negate().

  return function(x) {   // 4. A function is returned from the negate() call
    return !func(x);     //     that invokes the "isNaN" function, and returns
  };                     //     the logical opposite of its return value.

}

                  // 2. The built in "isNaN" function is passed to negate()
var isNotNaN = negate(isNaN);
 // 5. The function returned from negate() is assigned to the "isNotNaN" variable

         // 6. The "isNotNaN" function is invoked, and passed the "NaN" value.
show(isNotNaN(NaN));
 // 7. The result returned from "isNotNaN" is passed to the show() function.
```

The end result is that you have a function that returns the opposite of the `isNaN` function.

Seems like overkill when you can just call `isNaN` with `!` yourself.

```
show( !isNaN(NaN) );  // gives the same result
```

Comment: @patrick dw  thank you for your explanation. in step 4, what is the logical opposite of the return value of isNaN?

Comment: @mjmitche: You're welcome. The `isNaN` function always returns a boolean value (true or false). The `!` logical NOT operator gives you the opposite of the boolean value of whatever comes after it. So if `isNaN` returns `true`, the `!` will make it `false`, and vice versa.

Comment: ...when I say *"the opposite of the boolean value", obviously `true` and `false` are themselves booleans, so it just provides the opposite. But every type in javascript has some sort of boolean value, so sometimes the `!` is used to coerce it to its opposite boolean. For example, any string (except an empty string) is considered `true` (or is commonly called "truthy"). So if my string is "patrick", and a non-empty string is truthy, then `!"patrick"` gives me `false`. I can flip it again with another `!`, so `!!"patrick"` gives me `true`.

Comment: ...since the `isNaN` function tells you if the value you passed it is a number (or can be successfully converted to a number), then doing `!isNaN()` will give you the opposite of that result. In other words it says *"this is not not a number"* or in other words *"this is (or can be) a number"*.

Comment: @patrick dw  thank you.  by "built-in function" I`m guessing you mean that isNan is pre-set by Javascript to mean something? isnotanumber?? if so, how does it relate to Nan?

Comment: @mjmitche: Yes, the `isNaN` function could be reworded as `isNotANumber()`, and is used to test if something is a number, or can be converted to a number. The `NaN` (Not A Number) value is a special value that is given when an attempt is made to convert something to a number, but the value can not be successfully converted. Javascript gives you this `NaN` value as the result of that failure.

Comment: @mjmitche: Are you familiar with the developer tools your web browser gives you, like the console? If so, I'd go through and just start typing in test values for `isNaN()` and see what they give you. Also, to attempt a `toNumber` conversion on any value, you can precede it with a `+`. So `+"1"` is converted to `1`, but `+"patrick"` gives you `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Defines `negate()` function.
2. Sets variable `isNotNaN` to return of `negate(isNaN)`.
3. `negate()` returns a function, whilst keeping scope to `func` (in this case `isNaN`).
4. Call `show()` with `isNotNan(NaN)` (passing not a number to negation of `isNaN`). Same as `( ! isNaN(NaN))`.

Answer (score 2):

The code defines a function "negate" that takes as a parameter *another* function. The "negate" function itself returns yet another function, one which returns the boolean opposite of the result of calling the parameter function on the parameter passed in.

Then the code defines a variable, "isNotNan", and sets it equal to the result of calling "negate" with a function (which we don't see here) called "isNaN".  Calling *that* function with the constant `NaN` is effectively the same as calling `!isNaN(NaN)`, which is `false` because `NaN` is `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

when you call the function negate it creates a closure around the function you pass into it. so when you call isNotNaN it is actually running isNaN which has been enclosed within the function and then negates it with the boolean not operator "!".

Answer (score 1):

```
function negate(func) {
  return function(x) {
    return !func(x);
  };
}
var isNotNaN = negate(isNaN);
show(isNotNaN(NaN));
```

Lets start from the top:

```
function negate( func )
{
  ...
}
```

Declares a function `negate` with a parameter `func`. The function returns an anonymous function:

```
function(x)
{
  return !func(x);
}
```

The anonymous function will execute the function provided in the original function's `func` parameter, but negate the return vaule.

Then isNotNaN is set as a function that will return `true` when the parameter is *not* `NaN`, and `false` when the parameter *is* `NaN`;

```
var isNotNaN = negate( isNaN );
```

Finally `NaN` is chucked into the function returning the expected result of `false`

```
show( isNotNaN( NaN ) );
```